# git CLI commands error after upgrading to XCode 8

Tags: xcode, git, xcode8

I saw App Store reporting an upgrade to XCode 8 this morning and unfortunately, took the bait. Now, none of the git CLI commands are working. Tried searching on SO and Google but did not find anything helpful, though I did find recent posts of other issues after upgrading to XCode 8. Getting the same error for any git command - as shown below:

```
%> git status
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /usr/local/lib/libwep: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10F0E5000, size=0x0000F000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/local/lib/libwep
        /usr/local/lib/libwep: mmap() error 1 at address=0x10F103000, size=0x0000F000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/local/lib/libwep
git: error: unable to locate xcodebuild, please make sure the path to the Xcode folder is set correctly!
git: error: You can set the path to the Xcode folder using /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch
```

As it says, `/usr/local/lib/libwep` **does** exist but there is an error when trying to load it. Also, the xcodebuild executable also exists at the path printed in the message, i.e. at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild`

I also see another `xcodebuild` at `/usr/bin/xcodebuild` but `/` is not accepted as a valid `DEVELOPER_DIR` value. Some more possibly useful information: I have Github Desktop installed. So I made a change in one of the source files in my Git repo, and Github Desktop showed the local change successfully in its GUI. However, neither `git diff` nor `git status` works from the command-line.

I also tried cloning a fresh local repo but `git clone` throws the same error, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is not related to XCode. I found the following after some searching: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7862

So, libwep is used by WebSense, an application that is installed by default on all computers in the corporate environment I am working in. It is meant for security and restricts certain operations. For example, I can not execute any Heroku CLI commands, either, because of it.

What threw me off was that, even with WebSense, I **was** able to run git CLI commands until last week, but then I also installed a new version of the WebSense client late last week. So it may be the new WebSense version that is now blocking git CLI commands, too. That I installed XCode 8 today could be just a coincidence, or another possibility is that the XCode 8 upgrade **in combination with** the WebSense client upgrade resulted in this situation.

Anyway, thankfully, Github Desktop still seems to work so I'll just have to use that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't develop anything on Xcode just delete Xcode from program files and run git from CLI again. The required tools will be downloaded automatically. No issues.

Answer (score -1):

I did have the same issue this morning when I tried to use my git.  I had to go in and delete the program and reinstall the git client for mac.  It started working for me after that.